# List Attachment

Tags: list, attachments, ssom

Can you give me a brief on how Attachment List is linked to a specific item and how does it work, I want to customize it to filter the attached documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each item SharePoint creates folders for storing attachments.

The URL format is

```
http://weburl/Lists/<listname>/Attachments/<listItemID>
```

You can also check it with the REST-URL:

```
http://weburl/<site>/_api/Lists/getbytitle('<ListName>')/items?$select=ID,Attachments,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

Comment: Thank you Amal, but when I access to the link, it shows me that the folder is empty even though I have three files attached

Comment: Can you post the url you tried

Comment: https://portal.testfarm.com/Lists/TestAddItem/Attachments/97
But I get redirected to 
https://portal.testfarm.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/TestAddItem/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fLists%2fTestAddItem%2fAttachments%2f97&FolderCTID=0x012001

Comment: Is 97 the list item Id which has attachments?

Comment: yes, if i try another empty ID it returns error404

Comment: Ok I don't think the URL will list the documents. To answer your question the attachments are linked to each item based on that URL.

Comment: Thank you,
indeed, the URL do not show the documents, it uses a view from the parent list but I can now manipulate documents using this URL